# Xml Document Load giving Error Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: xml, xsd, xmlreader

I am trying to validate the xml using the xsd(xml schema)
I have tried all the answers in Stack Overflow but none of them works for me.
I get the exception at document.Load line.
Do I have to update the xml?
The xml's first line is this:

< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
I added an extra space after '<' because it wasn't showing. It's not in the actual xml

```
 try
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Schemas.Add(@"D:\test-files\xsd", "xsd\\indeedschema.xsd");
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("xsd\\inxml.xml", settings);
            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();   
            document.Load(reader);

            ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);

            document.Validate(eventHandler);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```